# How to install Masonry with bower

Tags: gulp, bower, masonry

I'm trying to install Masonry using bower and gulp. The depandencies and overrides:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "superfish": "~1.7.6",
    "masonry": "~3.3.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "jquery": {
      "ignore": true
    },
    "masonry": {
        "main": ["./dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"]
    }
  }
```

In my console I get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined**

The packaged version of Masonry contains all the dependecies yet I still get this error.

In my gulpfile I have this task to create the bower.js file with all the vendor packages:

```
gulp.task('js:bower:bootstrap', function () {
    /*
     * Custom bootstrap javascript build
     */
    var BS = SRC_FOLDER + '/bower_components/bootstrap';

    return gulp.src([
        BS + '/js/transition.js',
        BS + '/js/alert.js',
        BS + '/js/button.js',
        // BS + '/js/carousel.js',
        BS + '/js/collapse.js',
        BS + '/js/dropdown.js',
        BS + '/js/modal.js',
        BS + '/js/tooltip.js',
        BS + '/js/popover.js',
        BS + '/js/scrollspy.js',
        BS + '/js/tab.js',
        BS + '/js/affix.js',
    ])
    .pipe( concat('bootstrap.js') )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( TMP_FOLER + '/bootstrap/') );
});

gulp.task('js:bower', ['js:bower:bootstrap'], function () {
    /*
     * Build all bower javascript components
     */
    return gulp.src( mainBowerFiles([
        '**/*.js',
        '!**/bootstrap/**/bootstrap.js'
    ])).pipe( addsrc([
        TMP_FOLER + '/bootstrap/*.js'
    ]) )
    .pipe( concat('bower.js') )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( DST_FOLDER + '/js/' ) )
    .pipe( rename({ suffix: '.min' }) )
    .pipe( uglify() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( DST_FOLDER + '/js/' ) );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

What command did you try to install Masonry?

The [Masonry homepage](http://masonry.desandro.com/#package-managers) says to use:

Bower: `bower install masonry --save`

(Or with npm: `npm install masonry-layout`)

Also, if you are trying to use "masonry.pkgd.min.js", then it needs to be placed to the HTML and added as a `<script src="/path/to/the/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I use bower install masonry --save.The masonr.pkgd.min.js is included in the bower.js file that I create using Gulp.